# Regular expression accepts all special characters except space

Tags: regex

I gave validation using  **regEx** for not allowing special characters. But I want to give space within that **regEx**. How will I do this?

I have already created the **regEx** as follows for not allowing special characters

```
@"^([A-Za-z0-9])*"
```

how to include space within this?

Comment: You mean, how you include the space? Like `@"^([A-Za-z0-9 ])*"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to *add* space to the set of allowed characters, just insert it into the character class.

```
@"^([A-Za-z0-9 ])*"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just keep adding the characters you want to **match** to your character class `[]`

```
@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 ])*"
```

**Note**: The above regular expression will only capture the last character match, if you want the whole match I would move the outside capture bracket `)` to the right side of the quantifier.

```
@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)"
```